# How to always show notification on Android using cordova-plugin-local-notifications

Tags: android, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I got the plugin to work. Its great, but I am not an android user neither have an android to test it with.
With what I got to see from the emulator, notifications do not show when the app is open. It plays a sound and add a bell icon on the status bar. Is this the default behavior? My app wont be scheduling any tasks for the future, it will receive some info via web sockets that I would like to explicitly show to the user. I was expecting something like a ios banner to pop of the screen. Is this possible?